# Find the highest Score from each User from Submissions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

I am trying to write a method, unsuccessfully so far.

I have three models interacting: User, Submission and Score

Score has a submission_id, Submission has a user_id.

Users submitted anywhere from 1-5 submissions and then they received a score on each of those submissions. Now I need to find the highest score of all the submissions per each user.

For example, if user 1 submitted 2 photos and the 1st submission scored 25 and the second scored 50, I need the method to return 50 for that user.

I need to improve my skillset when it comes to arrays and ranges, but here is the speedy response one of my team members passed to me before he ran out the door:

"The way I would have done it is to go over all Submissions and store each in a hash with the key being the user_id and the value an array with the score. So if you have 2+ submissions for the same user_id, it will point to an array of scores. Once you have the hash, just go over each element of the array and pick the highest score. Then you store the score in another hash, but this time the score is the key and the value is an array of all the user_id with that score."

If you can help me out, I will be much obliged. I'm not lazy, just exhausted and I can't think straight anymore.

Here is the relevant information:

User Model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :submissions, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

Submission model:

```
class Submission < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :contest_id, :description, :title, :user_id, :video, :image_attributes,
                  :comment_show
  default_scope order: 'submissions.created_at DESC'
  belongs_to :user
  has_one :score, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

Score model:

```
class Score < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :effort, :innovation, :passion, :photo_contest_1, :reputation, 
                  :scorable_id, :scorable_type, :technical, :uniqueness, :submission_id,
                  :sub_total

  belongs_to :submission
end
```

[Edit]

So, I am using a `helper_method :contest_score` in the application controller, like this:

```
def contest_score
   User.joins(submissions: :score).maximum(:sub_total, group: 'users.id')  
end
```

Or:

```
def contest_score
  hashed_scores = Submission.joins(:score)
                      .select('max(scores.sub_total) as max_score, submissions.user_id as user_id')
                      .group('submissions.user_id')
                      .map { |subm| Hash[subm.user_id, subm.max_score] }
                      .reduce(&:merge)
end
```

Then, I am rendering in the user show template as each members high score in the contest:

```
 <%= contest_score %> contest points<br/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
scores = User.joins(submissions: :score).maximum(:sub_total, group: 'users.id')
```

This will result in a hash with keys equal to the `user_id` and with values equal to the highest score out of all the submissions.

UPDATE:

Here is how to get the results joined by highest scores

```
scores.inject({}) do |hash, (user_id, score)|
  hash[score] ||= []
  hash[score]  << user_id
  hash
end
```

UPDATE: No need to go from `User`

```
Score.joins(:submission).maximum(:sub_total, group: 'submissions.user_id')
```

Comment: Tried the top one out and got the same two values: {6565=>"15", 4968=>"7"}. The highest score is 100, so maybe there's something I haven't provided, information wise. Let me revise the question by adding an addendum.

Comment: @BrianMcDonough is the sub_total the column with the actual score?

Comment: Yes. sub_total is the only score that matters.

Comment: can you check the values on your db?  @Ismael Abreu also got the same result

Comment: @jvnill, I edited the question to give more information. Got the same values from the console as well. I think maybe I have not phrased the question correctly, but also do not know what may be missing.

Comment: can you look at a certain user. preferably the one with ID 6565 and get the highest score. btw, i've updated my answer

Comment: okay, I got it working, but now I need to get the right value out of the array for each user to display their highest scoring photo on their user>show page. I'll create another question though, since you have answered this one

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can do this. It will use one query and give you the data you need.

```
hashed_scores = Submission.joins(:score)
                          .select('max(scores.sub_total) as max_score, submissions.user_id as user_id')
                          .group('submissions.user_id')
                          .map { |subm| Hash[subm.user_id, subm.max_score] }
                          .reduce(&:merge)
```

This should be away more efficient then your solution since it only hits the database one time and also there is no need to sort the scores and select only the max ones since the database can do it for you.

Comment: Okay, I changed :scores to :score, then got this error: `PG::Error: ERROR:  column "submissions.created_at" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`

Comment: Try it now there was missing a `do`.

Comment: Oh! That's because you have a default scope maybe.

Comment: Okay, removed that and got two return values: {6565=>"15", 4968=>"7"}

Comment: You just got that? :s And you have lots of submissions, users and scores?

Comment: There are 1400 submissions and 1400 scores from 600 members